# Modifying a collection while enumerating another one

Tags: c#, collections, xna, enumeration, monogame

I want to delete every coin that has the delete boolean set to true, and I know I can't delete it from the same collection the foreach is iterating over. So I made a copy (temp) but it keeps throwing the same exception:

> Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute.

What am I doing wrong? Here's my code:

```
List<Coin> temp = coins;
foreach (Coin c in coins)
{
    if (c.delete)
        temp.Remove(c);
    else
        c.somethingElse();
}
coins = temp;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simplest thing to do here is to call `coins.RemoveAll(coin => coin.delete);`. (google `List.RemoveAll`). That leaves you with a list of coins with all the "deletes" removed in one statement, no need to worry about counters or loop variables or temp copies or whatever at all.  So then you can iterate over the remaining coins doing whatever you want.

```
coins.RemoveAll(coin => coin.delete);
foreach (var coin in coins)
    coin.somethingElse();
```

If you need a faster implementation that only iterates through the list once, here's what you'd need.  Don't use any solution with `Remove` or `RemoveAt` in a loop because those are slow operations, so using them in a loop will *kill* performance.  The below will just move each "good" coin down to the `index` position and then increment `index`, so at any time all the "good" coins are below `index`.  Finally you remove all the coins above `index`, so you've got only "good" coins left.  Since it only iterates once, it's about 2x faster than the `RemoveAll` option, and *way* faster than any of the solutions `Remove` or `RemoveAt` in a loop.

```
var index = 0;
for (var i = 0; i < coins.Count; ++i)
{
    var coin = coins[i];
    if (!coin.delete)
    {
        coin.somethingElse();
        coins[index++] = coin;
    }
}
coins.RemoveRange(index, coins.Count - index);
```

Comment: That's pretty amazing, but is it efficient? I mean, there wouldn't you be doing two iterations over the list? (I don't know how the RemoveAll method works internally)

Comment: You can't really avoid 2 iterations when using a foreach to remove items due to the collection modification limitation. It might be possible to make it slightly more more efficient with a for loop instead of foreach, but probably not worth it in most cases. Readability vs premature optimization.

Comment: @Nico it's going to be faster than removing each element one at a time; `List.Remove` is a relatively slow operation so even though you're only iterating once, you're calling that slow operation multiple times.  One call to `List.RemoveAll` will outperform that any day.  If performance is absolutely key and you don't care about the order of your coins, you can use a `HashSet<Coin>` instead of a `List<Coin>`.

Comment: I don't know if the performance here is so important, it's for a monogame game. At least for now I'll use the 'for instead foreach' option.

Comment: @Nico I tried it out and `HashSet` turned out to be slower anyway.  `HashSet` is faster for determining if your set/list contains a certain element, but slower for inserting and deleting than a `List`.

Comment: Ordinarily I agree that premature optimization is the root of all evil.  However, avoiding garbage collection in XNA Update logic isn't premature optimization.  So I suggest not using lambdas and foreach as a matter of principle in this type of situation.  A "backwards" for loop is best, in my opinion.

Comment: @WolfRevokCats Profile before making performance assumptions.  On my PC, doing this in a reverse loop using `RemoveAt` with 300K elements takes 91129 ms, whereas the above solution runs in 3 ms.  `RemoveAt` is a **slow** operation because it has to shift all the elements each time through the loop.  `RemoveAll` never shifts an element more than once.  https://gist.github.com/daxfohl/6143558

Comment: @Nico I added an implementation that only iterates through the loop once.  It runs about 2 times as fast as the `RemoveAll` solution.

Comment: @DaxFohl: yes, a much better approach in your second snippet. Since yours is the accepted answer, which is fine, you might consider adding a note to steer people away from your first snippet and toward your second. You're right that RemoveAt is a slow method, but generating heap garbage (as in your first answer) is in some ways worse than slow -- it's non-deterministically slow and will cause an ugly GC interruption that will freeze the whole game experience. Cheers.

Comment: @DaxFohl also note that I made no assumptions about performance (avoiding GC in XNA Update is not a performance assumption subject to profiling).  But just for fun, I took your profiling test and changed the assumptions a little bit.  Check it out: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/6148807

Comment: @WolfRevokCats you're creating the list once *outside* the loop.  So all the elements get removed in the first iteration, and the remaining iterations do nothing.  If clone the list for each iteration, `RemoveAt` is still much slower.  `RemoveAt` is only faster when there is nothing to remove.

Comment: @Dax Fohl -- yep, exactly my point.  If the real world purpose involves frequently scanning, but very infrequently removing, then it may be the case that the RemoveAt approach becomes faster, as it doesn't involve copying the entire array.  It just depends on the actual use in the program. If I had an array that was constantly churning, then I'd concur with your suggestion to avoid RemoveAt. Again, it just depends, and use of a profiler (as opposed to somewhat artificial benchmarks) can be relied on to show which is better in a real life situation. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

> What am I doing wrong?

The reason your code doesn't work is because you are only copying the *reference* to the coins variable. A like a pointer in C, a reference is nothing but a variable that holds the memory address of another type. So the temp variable is pointing at the exact same collection as the coins variable.

> So I made a copy (temp)

What your code is *intended* to do (as you describe it) is this:

```
List<Coin> temp = coins.ToList();
foreach (Coin c in coins)
{
    if (c.delete)
        temp.Remove(c);
    else
        c.somethingElse();
}
coins = temp;
```

(see [Enumerable.ToList](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb342261.aspx))

As Dax has already mentioned, there are also other, shorter ways to achieve the same result. List.RemoveAll is a perfectly acceptable solution in this case. You might also want to look into [LINQ queries](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397933.aspx).

Comment: Thanks man, I didn't know that = only copied the reference, but I guess it makes sense since you cand redefine it. Would vote up if had enough rep :P

Comment: Happy to help. This problem has tripped me up a few times. You can't redefine assignment operators (=) in C# (for good reason). http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8edha89s(v=vs.71).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Since you tagged your question with "xna" and "monogame", you may benefit from a solution that avoids generating garbage (heap memory allocations that will trigger subsequent garbage collector churning).  Here's what I'd use, which also works in any programming language with a list type data structure, even if the magic of LINQ isn't available:

```
// Iterate the list backwards so we never skip items or accidentally
// access past the end of the list.
for (int i = coins.Count - 1; i >= 0; --i)
{
   if (coins[i].delete)
   {
      coins.RemoveAt(i);
   }
   else
   {
      coins[i].somethingElse();
   }
}
```

In @DaxFohl's solution, I believe that the creation of a lambda ("coin => coin.delete") will allocate garbage memory on the heap.  And it's also possible that the enumeration will allocate from the heap, at least in Mono.  I've heard a rumor that Microsoft's canonical .NET implementation on Windows has those enumerations super-optimized w.r.t. memory usage, but I like to play it on the safe side in my own game logic.

On the other hand, if this isn't an inner loop specimen of your logic (e.g. called very frequently in the Update method), then it may not matter so much if a little bit of garbage is generated here.

Comment: That's cool bro; and yes, it's called inside the update method of my game, it's a way of disposing the coins my player collected. What are you developing?

Comment: A physics based game for iOS, Android, Win8, WP and OS X.  Hence staying really basic so everything works well on MS .NET as well as Mono is important to me.  Good luck with your project!